# How to pass data between two react components having no relation

Tags: reactjs

I have a component called header and another one called sidebar I want to pass data from `Header` to `Sidebar` but there is no relation between them can anyone help me out  ?

Comment: How is there no relation. Surely they are both children or grandchildren of some sort of your `app.js`?

Comment: use the redux store, that will be a good way to share data globally within the application

Comment: It would be better to write the code @venkatasai

Comment: It's easier for everyone if you provide a [mcve]. You can use the [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) feature to embed runnable HTML/JavaScript/CSS into your question. You can [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: Ya in the app component i have header and sidebar .But i have a event based on condition i want to hide and show the sidebar

Comment: My app component is a stateless component and i have two siblings header and sidebar how to communicate between these siblings

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by sending the data to the common Parent component. If the hierarchy is deep then it's better to use [Redux](https://redux.js.org/).

Reference: [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can [Use Prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)

```
var text = "Click the button";

var Form = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>{this.props.text}</h3>
                <input type="submit" />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <h1> Welcome to my app!</h1>
                <Form text={this.props.text}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
React.render(<App text={text}/>,  document.getElementById("app"));
```

Or redux to pass data to sate of redux and call anywhere [read more](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react)

[examples redux and react](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos-with-undo)